# Is it absolutely safe to commit Fragment Transaction in onClick event?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I am not wrong, `View`'s onClick events are queued up at the end of the main thread `MessageQueue`. So there is no guarantee about when it will be executed. Therefore, it could be executed after `Activity.onSaveInstanceState()` has been called which causes `IllegalStateException` to be thrown.

#### So my question is:

Is it absolutely safe to commit Fragment Transaction (using `commitNow()`) in onClick event?

Comment: I commit a Fragment Transaction soon after setting the Fragment.

Comment: Yeah. If you want to replace a `Fragment` with another one when the user click on a button, what would u do ?

Comment: The very same. Commit soon after the replacement.

Comment: We don't know how soon that is right? before or after `onSaveInstanceState()` ?

Comment: I can't understand the problem. `onSaveInstanceState()` only occurs when the Activity is (re)created. I.e.: when you rotate your device. It doesn't occur on clicking.

Comment: Yes. I agree too. My point is when you are clicking and very quickly rotating the device or you are rotating and the main thread is busy doing something else then you click on a view. Do u think it could happen ?

Comment: Never tested. I guess you need to hire a monkey and let it test your app ;)

Comment: Yeah yeah. I agree it is very hard to reproduce and I can't as well. But It can when the app is in production

Comment: Well... add a warning which says "Not tested against monkeys". ;)